# How can i assign different color for different bars in mpandroidchart?

Tags: android, dataset, mpandroidchart

I want to assign color for different bars. In my code, it assign color for barDataSets but i want to assign for bar entrys'. How can i do that?
Thank You!

```
     private ArrayList<BarDataSet> getDataSet() {
        ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataSets = null;
        //1. Cubuk
        ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet1 = new ArrayList<>();
        BarEntry v1e1 = new BarEntry(10.000f, 0); // Değer olarak frekans ortalaması alınacak.

        valueSet1.add(v1e1);
        BarEntry v1e2 = new BarEntry(40.000f, 1); 
        valueSet1.add(v1e2);
        BarEntry v1e3 = new BarEntry(60.000f, 2); 
        valueSet1.add(v1e3);
       .
       .
       .
        //2. Cubuk
        ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet2 = new ArrayList<>();
       .
       .
       .
        BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(valueSet1, "Brand 1");
        barDataSet1.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 155, 0));

        BarDataSet barDataSet2 = new BarDataSet(valueSet2, "Brand 2");
        barDataSet2.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

        dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        dataSets.add(barDataSet1);
        dataSets.add(barDataSet2);
        return dataSets;
    }
```

Comment: I think i solve problem by creating color array and assign it to bardataset;         int color[] = {Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.GRAY};
         barDataSet2.setColors(color);

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [`setColors`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v2.1.6/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/DataSet.html#setColors(int[])) method on your `DataSet`.

> `public void setColors(int[] colors)`
>
> Sets the colors that should be used for this `DataSet`. Colors are reused as soon as the number of `Entries` the `DataSet` represents is higher than the size of the colors array. If you are using colors from the resources, make sure that the colors are already prepared (by calling `getResources().getColor(...)`) before adding them to the `DataSet`.